# How to retrieve the sender email address

Tags: vba, outlook

I've written a Macro in Outlook 2013 where I need to retrieve the sender email address as a string

A simple version is

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim oMail As MailItem
Set oMail = Item

Dim sender as String
sender = oMail.SenderEmailAddress 

End Sub
```

The above works great.

I now have added a new email account to Outlook and this is where the issue is.

If I create a new email it uses my default@mail.com email address. If I then change the account from which to send the email from (to myOtherAccount@mail.com), the SenderEmailAddress within the VBa does not reflect this change... It still shows (in the watch window) as default.mail.com

How can I get Outlook to re-check the sender (as I assume it's caching it some where)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All sender related properties are set *after* the `ItemSend` event fires. The earliest you can see sender properties is when the `Items.ItemAdd` event fires on the Sent Items folder.

Comment: Right, so the reason is by design? That is fine, do you know of a work around? Outlook clearly knows which email to send from (since it is sent from the correct account), I'm wondering if the values are exposed via a property/method call?

Comment: Check the value of the MailItem.SendUsingAccount. If that property is null, assume that the default account will be used. You can then read the Account.SmtpAddress property.

Comment: Than you, `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` was the answer

Comment: Just make sure you can handle SendUsingAccount returning NULL - it is not guaranteed to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Just define your folder in the application:startup

```
Public Sub Application_Startup()

Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentbox)
```

End Sub

Then just change your code above to the itemAdd Event
like

```
Private Sub myFolder_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

senderEmail = Item.SendUsingAccount