# Outlook attachment check

Tags: vba, email, outlook, attachment, email-attachments

How do I make a VBA code or set up my mail in a way so that a message box shows up if I am sending an email with an attachment? 
I have searched through many posts and haven't found a solution to this problem - I have found many solutions to check for missing attachments but so far I haven't found one where an alert is shown if an email has an attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Application.ItemSend

and [How can I automatically run a macro when an email is sent in Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806335/how-can-i-automatically-run-a-macro-when-an-email-is-sent-in-outlook)

as well as https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c4f47790-8e7b-425a-bf7e-f7bc5b725e81/determine-attechments-in-mail-item?forum=outlookdev

These detail the ItemSend event with the example shown below.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim prompt As String
prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?"
If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then
    Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The property of the `MailItem` you're looking for is `Attachments`.

The above example passes in the Item as an object-which should be a `MailItem` by default, so checking `Item.Attachments.Count <> 0` would be true if it had attachments.

Try something along the lines of

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item as Object, Cancel as Boolean)
If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
   If Msgbox("Items attached to email. Send?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
     Cancel = True
   End If
End If
End Sub
```

To only flag messages with attachments at the subject line we can use the Attachment Property "PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN" If it exists and the value is FALSE, it indicates an attached-at-subject-line attachment as opposed to an embedded image.

The quick On Error Resume Next is to catch the exception if PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN isn't on any objects.  It will throw an exception if it doesn't exist.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Const PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B"

Dim aFound As Boolean

aFound = False

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

        For Each a In Item.Attachments
            On Error Resume Next ' to avoid the error thrown when no items within attachments have this property

            If a.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN) = False Then
                aFound = True
                Exit For
            End If

            On Error GoTo 0
         Next a

        If aFound = True Then
            If MsgBox("Items attached to email. Send?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If you are trying to discriminate between images within signatures and embedded images we need to review the content ID against the HTML body of the email for the tag.  I added another check to the code to find those and disregard them as false positives.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"
Const PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B"

Dim aFound As Boolean

aFound = False

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

        For Each a In Item.Attachments
            On Error Resume Next ' to avoid the error thrown when no items within attachments have this property
            If a.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN) = False Then
                If Len(a.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID)) > 0 And InStr(Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.HTMLBody, a.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID)) Then
                Else
                aFound = True
                Exit For
                End If
            End If

            On Error GoTo 0
         Next a

        If aFound = True Then
            If MsgBox("Items attached to email. Send?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - It is working! I just have one additional question now because I sometimes have pictures in my signature. Is it possible to design it so it doesn't count these without changing the number in the VBA code manually every time I have a different number of pictures?

Comment: What type of attachments are you sending?  Are you sending images IN your email or attaching them at the subject line?  Generally speaking trying to identify only the signature images is tricky unless you define a static list of them.

Comment: I am sending word-files and excel-files primarily and they are attached at the subject line, and I only want the message to show up, if I have something attached at the subject line, so it doesn't pop-up if i have a signature or something else in the body of the mail.

Comment: I can see that the code is now updated, but it still gives me the message box when I have no attachments but a picture in my signature. Maybe it is because that PR_Attachments_HIDDEN doesn't work for me?

Comment: See final code block.  Another check was added to review the content tag against the items in the email to ensure we don't mistakenly flag items that are embedded images.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much - it is working when I send emails now. Is there a way for it to work when I reply on mails and have attachments, because it only works when I send a mail.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why that's happening.  This is triggering every time I send, forward or reply to an email.

Comment: I have tried it for a week now, and it still won't show up when I reply to an email, but I want to thank you anyway - this really helped me still!